# How do you add HTML to the qq-drop-area-text in FineUploader?

Tags: html, css, fine-uploader

I'd like to add a Font Awesome Icon and other styling (e.g., `<em>`) to the `qq-drop-area-text` of [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html). Is this possible? It looks like the text is styled using a CSS `content` area.

Example HTML from FineUploader:

```
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here!">...</div>
```

Desired:

```
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="<span class='fa fa-upload'></span> Drop files <em>here</em>!">...</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't your proposed markup work?

Comment: @RayNicholus The Drop area is blank/empty when the template is parsed if I use HTML. If I edit the demos on the fly too, it doesn't work. The demos don't render the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.qq-uploader:before {
    /*content: attr(qq-drop-area-text) " ";*/
    font-family: FontAwesome, 'Open Sans', Arial;
    content: "\f0c5  Drop files here";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 200%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 45%;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

Here's my example where `f0c5` is the Unicode value for the Font Awesome icon I wanted to use. In this case it's the `fa-files-o` icon. Click any icon on the [Font Awesome list of icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) to display its Unicode value.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

To add more styles to the dropzone message, simply include the following in your project's CSS file:

```
.qq-uploader:before {
   // dropzone text styles go here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, my issue is with adding HTML to the drop zone. Styling it is okay.

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the existing CSS styles with your own? Fine Uploader doesn't prevent you from adding markup to your document. Most likely the :before style is causing some issue with your markup. I would suggest overwriting that rule.